# AngularJS notification system

Tags: angularjs, spring, web, service, frontend

I have a notification system in the backend but I don't know how to implement it in the frontend side.

I want to make an AngularJs service that listens for any requests from the server and then I will display the notification(like facebook notification).Is this possible ?

this to overcome the problem of sending request every "period"to the server.

Comment: I usually make a request to the back-end, and use a notification to notify the user about that said request. If you want angular to display a notification on a server event by himself, I think you should look into socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are listening for data sent by the server, I assume you are using WebSockets. There is https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket that slightly simplfies working with WebSockets in Angular.

---

If you are referring to PushNotifications, that is implemented in the ServiceWorker, not in the Angular app.

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    let data = event.data.json();
    let title = '', args = {};

    title = 'Notification!!';
    args = { 'body': 'Hello hello',
             'icon': '/static/icon64.png',
             'tag': 'some-tag' };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, args));
});
```

Comment: For anyone that looking for something similar, here's a good [tutorial](http://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can user SignalR for real time to build real time notification system . Just specify the hub name, listening functions, and methods that you're going to use.
This [library](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub) can be useful.